# CSS3 pop up navigation using list items

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to the site and to HTML/CSS coding. I have an assignment in which I am suppose to make a CSS generated pop up menu using lists. Here is my HTML I have for the navigation at the top of the page, whenever I try to change the height of the list items in the CSS to give it the pop up effect it pushes the rest of my content down rather than taking up the space above. Here is my code so far:

```css
  nav {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  nav li {
    width: 18%;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border: 5px solid black;
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
  }
  nav a {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
  }
  nav li:hover {
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 100px;
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menuItem">Home</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menuItem">Upcoming Flights</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menuItem">About Us</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menuItem">Travel Guide</div>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">
        <div class="menuItem">Contact Us</div>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Any advice?

Comment: Pleaase, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: im sorry im not too familiar with the terminology yet. Im suppose to be using css3 properties to create a pop up navigation on the top of my webpage. Something like this http://ista230.com/images/assignments/7/page2.jpg

Comment: I thought by adding a hover effect that made the height higher it would grow to the top like in the example i liked but it expands down and just pushes my content down which is where im having the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to have a negative margin-top and some extra padding-bottom that gets added on the hover. I also gave the nav a specified height and set the overflow to hidden but that's not entirely necessary. Certainly not the only way to do it either. [Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelwagner/5hketost/) to see it in action. Hope this helps.

```
nav { 
  height: 58px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav li {
  width: 16%;
  margin: 14px 0 0px 14px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px; 
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  float: left;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
} 

nav li:hover {
  margin-top: -10px;
  padding-bottom: 30px; 
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can have your menu pop up without pushing the content down:

```css
nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
nav ul {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
nav li {
  width: 18%;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: black;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
nav li:hover {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: -77px;
}
.clear {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menuItem">Home</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menuItem">Upcoming Flights</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menuItem">About Us</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menuItem">Travel Guide</div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <div class="menuItem">Contact Us</div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p>Here is the content</p>
  <p>Here is more content</p>
</body>

</html>
```

If you give the ul a fixed position, it does not effect the other elements on the page. Then, on hover, the margin for the li is -77px, so it's not pushing itself away from the top of the page. Perhaps a little bit hacked together, but as long as your page is run at a wide enough resolution, this should solve your problem.

Comment: While this works on full screen, on smaller screen there is some displacement.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant in the paragraph at the bottom. The original code has similar problems, I was just trying to solve the OP's question.